# mongoDB eval command is deprecated error Version 3.4

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting an error `the eval command is deprecated` while using mongo command in shell. How to get rid of it? It wasn't there few days back

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB [db.eval()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) command has been in deprecation mode since MongoDB v3.0.

Unless you really need to use `eval()`, please try other alternatives to it. Post a new question with your use case of the `eval` and others may be able to point you an alternative for it.